# Double tip arrow with upper symbol in Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

How can I write this diagram in Tikz:

[image]

Here is my try:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
x \arrow{leftrightarrow}{r}{*} \arrow[dashed]{dr}{*} & &  
y \arrow[dashed]{dl}{*}  \\
& z &
\end{tikzcd}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
x \arrow[rr, leftrightarrow, "*"] \arrow[dr, dashrightarrow, "*"'] 
 &  & y \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, "*"] \\
 & z &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** Another solution with pure Tik*Z*:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (x) at (0,0) {$x$};
 \node (y) at (2,0) {$y$};
 \node (z) at (1,-1) {$z$};

 \draw[<->] (x) -- node[above] {$\ast$} (y);
 \draw[->,dashed] (x) -- node[below left] {$\ast$} (z);
 \draw[->,dashed] (y) -- node[below right] {$\ast$} (z);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
x \arrow[dashed,"*"']{dr}\arrow[leftrightarrow]{rr}{*} & & y \arrow[dashed]{dl}{*}\\
& z &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, this is almost a bit silly. Two very similar solutions posted at almost the same time … If yours gets accepted, I will delete mine.

Comment: @JasperHabicht No, leave it. It's a different syntax. Someone will find it useful. P.S.: I tried to see which answer was the first one but it's easier to see if Han shot first :P

Answer (score 2):

A simple tikz solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[<->] (0,0) node[left] {$x$}--(4,0) node[midway, above]{$*$} node[right]{$y$};
  \draw[->,dashed] (0,0)--(2,-1.7) node[midway,below left]{$*$} node[below]{$z$};
  \draw[->,dashed] (4,0)--(2,-1.7) node[midway,below right]{*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The arrow heads collide. This could be prevented using `shorten >`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht it is an option, but it would be solved easier by another arrowhead like "-latex" instead of "->"